# Why is my flag dialog missing the "should be closed" option?

Tags: support, flagging

I just ran across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010008/ubuntu-18-04-beta-login-loop-after-failed-upgrade) and was going to flag it for closure as off topic (beta versions not supported until released) -- but the flag dialog only had spam, rude/abusive, and "other, needs moderator attention" options.  I used to get an option for "should be closed because", vaguely similar to what I get for a close vote on other SE where I have that privilege (and I used to have that option in the flag dialog on askubuntu SE).

Was this changed, or is it something specific to my account?

Answer (score 3):

The question is already closed.  That's why you don't see the "Should be closed" option.

This is the close reason box on the question, and yes I did cast a binding "Close vote" flag because it is indeed offtopic:

[image]

If you refresh the page where you're viewing the question it should show up now as "closed", and "[on hold]" in the title area alongside the original title.

Comment: I wondered about that, and reloaded the question before asking here.  It didn't show closed at that point.

Comment: I don't know when you hit "Reload" but the flags queue box is a separate web request so it'd know if it was closed or not